# Java: How to push the excel data in to java map(<string,ArrayList<Strings>)

Tags: java

I am facing a weird problem here, i need to read the excel data which starts after some rows.

My excel input is something like below

```
Row1 : This report is to display all the user details
Row2 : Kindly find the below details
Row3 : TABLE1 (This is the identifier after this row my table data is available).
Row4 : ID   Name  DOB
Row5 : 101  RAM  10-07-1986
Row6 : 102  Sita 24-08-1989
Row6 : Table2
```

note:i need to read only row4 to row6jav

I need the output like below in the map,
mymap [ID =[101,102],[Name = RAM,Sita],[DOB = 10-07-1986,24-08-1989]]

I have tried the below code which is working absolutely fine if my first 3 rows are not there, only creating issue if i give first 3 rows. your help is much appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\demo\\employee.xlsx");   //creating a new file instance
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);   //obtaining bytes from the file
        //creating Workbook instance that refers to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);     //creating a Sheet object to retrieve object
        Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();    //iterating over excel file

        // CAREFUL HERE! use LinkedHashMap to guarantee the insertion order!
        Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        // populate map with headers and empty list
        if (itr.hasNext()) {
            Row row = itr.next();
            Iterator<Cell> headerIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                myMap.put(getCellValue(cell), new ArrayList<>());
            }
        }

        Iterator<List<String>> columnsIterator;
        // populate lists
        while (itr.hasNext()) {

            // get the list iterator every row to start from first list
            columnsIterator = myMap.values().iterator();
            Row row = itr.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();   //iterating over each column
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                // here don't check hasNext() because if the file not contains problems
                // the # of columns is same as # of headers
                columnsIterator.next().add(getCellValue(cell));
            }
        }

        // here your map should be filled with data as expected

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String getCellValue(Cell cell) {
    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:    //field that represents string cell type
            return cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t\t";
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:    //field that represents number cell type
            return cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t\t";
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_Date:    //field that represents Date cell type
            return cell.getDateCellValue() + "\t\t\t";
        default:
            return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: The code assumes that the spreadsheet starts with a header row and then continues with data rows. If you are working with a fixed offset, just skipt the first n rows, otherwise you need some logic to find the start of the data. Depends on the shape of the data you have.

Comment: @Benjamin:That is my problem with above code, i am not able to find the way to skip first n rows.how can i start my iterator from nth row.